# How do you vertically list a string output and number them accordingly?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you multiply a string i.e "Enter Name" based on what number was entered in a input field and create a vertical numbered list based on said output. Any advice would be great!

Example:

1. hello name
2. hello name!
3. hello name
4. hello name!
5. hello name

etc.

Ive tried a couple of things. A loop seems like the logical answer, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'm still in the process of learning javascript so not everything is immediately apparent or obvious.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">   

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <label for="first-name">Frist Name!</label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name-text" id="first-name-text" placeholder="Enter a name">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="n-times">Number of times</label>
        <input type="text" name="n-times-text" id="n-times-text" placeholder="Enter a number">
    </div>


    <div>
        <p id="hello-message">Hello World!</p>

    </div>
<br>
    <div>
        <button id="hello-button">Display Hello!</button>
        <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>






</html>
```

javascript

```
let firstNameText = document.getElementById("first-name-text");
let helloMessage = document.getElementById("hello-message");

let nTimesText = document.getElementById("n-times-text")



function hideMessage( ) {
    helloMessage.style.display = "none";


}

function showMessage() {
    helloMessage.style.display = "";

}


function displaymessages(name) {





    // let helloMessage = document.getElementById("hello-message")
        helloMessage.innerText = "Hello " + name + "!";





    // let goodbyeMessage = document.getElementById("goodbye-message")
        // goodbyeMessage.innerText = "Goodbye " + name + "!";

        showMessage();
}



hideMessage();

let helloButton = document.getElementById("hello-button");
    helloButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let firstNameText = document.getElementById("first-name-text");



        displaymessages(firstNameText.value);
        console.log('first name:' + firstNameText.value);


});

let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        firstNameText.value = "";
        nTimesText.value = "";
        hideMessage();
    });
```

Comment: If number is `2` result is `"Enter NameEnter Name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to print line by line (vertically) then you have to use symbol "\n" and which will create new line.
I have changed your example code and see below,

```
function displaymessages(name, index) {      

    helloMessage.innerText += index + " " + "Hello " + name + "!\n";          

    showMessage();
}

 let helloButton = document.getElementById("hello-button");
 helloButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let firstNameText = document.getElementById("first-name-text");
    helloMessage.innerText = "";
    var numberTimes = parseInt(nTimesText.value)

    for (var i = 0; i < numberTimes ; i++) {
        displaymessages(firstNameText.value, (i + 1));
    }           
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.repeat()`.

```
let helloButton = document.getElementById("hello-button");
 helloButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let firstNameText = document.getElementById("first-name-text");
    displaymessages(firstNameText.value.repeat(+nTimesText.value));
    console.log('first name:' + firstNameText.value);
});
```

Comment: Okay, is there an easy way to number them and have them vertically spaced?                  `1. hello name
    2. hello name
    3  hello name
    4  hello name`